# chef cookbook with embedded roles

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, role, cookbook

I've created a chef cookbook, which has lot's of dependencies to other cookbooks. My main problem now is that the recipes from other cookbooks are executed in the random order. If I specify the execution of these recipes in the vagrant file like:

```
chef.add_recipe "gitlab::core_prereq"
chef.add_recipe "postfix"
chef.add_recipe "gitlab::users_prereq"
chef.add_recipe "rvm::vagrant"
chef.add_recipe "rvm::system"
chef.add_recipe "ohai"
chef.add_recipe "nginx"
chef.add_recipe "gitlab::python_tools_prereq"
chef.add_recipe "gitlab::gitolite_prereq"
chef.add_recipe "gitlab::gitlab_install"
```

Everything works fine, but I would like to have this spec in the recipe, so that a user just needs to include the default recipe and gets everything needed installed in the right order.

How can I solve this? Should I use a role? I don't get it from the chef docs, if the role can be specified within a recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess not all of your recipes can be installed on clean machine. But they should be. If some recipe "A" has some prerequisitives, then you should add that required recipes into recipe "A" using `include_recipe`.

In your case I guess that **gitlab::gitlab_install** requires **gitlab::gitolite_prereq** and **gitlab::python_tools_prereq**. That means you should add to your `cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab_install.rb`:

```
incude_recipe 'gitlab::gitolite_prereq'
incude_recipe 'gitlab::python_tools_prereq'
```

You can also include recipes from other cookbookss this way. For exampple **ohai** requires **rvm::system**. Add to `cookbooks/ohai/recipes/default.rb`:

```
incude_recipe 'rvm::system'
```

and add to `cookbooks/ohai/metadata.rb`:

```
depends 'rvm'
```

This way you will not have to write all the recipes in some exact order, and you don't have to write all the dependencies, they will be installed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I understand you, I should put all the stuff into a single recipe, instead of splitting them logically??? Do you may be have another suggestion? I don't want to have a one big mess in a single file. I used include_recipe, but these are executed out of order. I don't like the idea of modifying 3rd party cookbooks, since I would like to make them upgradable to newer versions in the future without needing any merges etc.

Comment: You were right... Needed to make the gitlab::install recipe self-contained, i.e. put all dependencies there. Than everything workd! Thanks.